# Delete a 0 byte object from S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

How can I delete files of 0bytes from amazon s3 bucket? 
If I try to download this file, AWS give me this error:

```
<Error>
<Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
<Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
<Key>css/Icon </Key>
</Error>
```

But I cannot delete the bucket because there is this file...

Comment: Are you sure it's a file and not a leftover version?

Comment: @OleksiiDonoha How can I verify? How can I remove it?

Comment: If you list the bucket, does it show the object's key? If you use `aws s3 rm s3://mybucket/mykey` to delete the key what happens?

Comment: Have you tried deleting the object through the S3 management console? Sometimes there's strange character in the Key (filename) that makes it hard to delete.

Comment: I see this Object URL => https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/test-bucket123.it/css/Icon%0A. I think that the problem is a special char...line feed?
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The file name contain a line feed at the end.
You can remove file with aws-cli:

```
aws s3 rm s3://BUCKET/css/Icon\r
```